# imenu list automatically toggled in new frame

Tags: init-file, imenu

I tried to run imenu-list-show in hook which is called after frame creation but it doesnt work as expected.
It toggled the imenu-list in new frame but my keyboard arrows become unresponsive.

Code is:

```
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
          (lambda (new-f)
            (select-frame new-f)
            (imenu-list-show)))
```

Comment: I'ver tried your code and the arrows keys are working fine (GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (OSX)). Maybe you should try it starting Emacs with "emacs -Q" and debug your init code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works normally now, dont know why, but this code needed full emacs restart to works good.